# SQL Server - trigger AFTER INSERT table in schema

Tags: sql-server, triggers, database-trigger

I have a stored procedure to run after a set of tables, all belonging to the same schema `[DATA_Countries]`, is dropped and then re-inserted.

The operation is performed by another application, which drops and recreates the target table, over which I have no control.

Since the table is dropped and recreated each time, I can not use triggers on each target table.

Is there a way to get a trigger for each time a table is inserted into a specific schema, to return the name of such table and launch a parametrized stored procedure?

Thanks!

Comment: You can create Database triggers, yes, which can trigger on DDL changes. The Trigger would start `CREATE TRIGGER [YourTriggername] ON DATABASE FOR CREATE_TABLE AS...`. Have a look at [CREATE TRIGGER (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql).

Comment: Thanks. Have created an AFTER database trigger and it works.

Any idea on how I would access the name/schema of the table that is being inserted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can create DDL Triggers on SQL Server to track the DDL Changes. For example, If I want to track the changes in Stored Procedures on my Database AdventureWorks, I can create a trigger like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER td_ProcTrack 
ON AdventureWorks
FOR CREATE_PROCEDURE, ALTER_PROCEDURE, DROP_PROCEDURE
AS
BEGIN

<my code>

END
```

Refer this [Article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2085/sql-server-ddl-triggers-to-track-all-database-changes/) for more detailed examples